# How to handle or ignore NAs when using ifelse to mutate a new column with multiple conditions (solved)

Tags: r, if-statement, na, dplyr

I am a newcomer to dplyr and tried to create a new composite variable from three different age variables using dplyr and `ifelse`. I made a data frame to explain the situation as follows:

```
library(dplyr)

z <- data.frame("j6" = c(6, 19, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, 20, 20, NA), 
                "j7" = c(27, 20, NA, 7, 19, NA, NA, 20, 30, 9, NA),
                "j8" = c(8, 22, NA, 20, NA, 8, 30, NA, NA, NA, 3))

z <- z %>% 
        mutate(., age_event = NA) %>% 
        mutate(., age_event = ifelse(j6 < 18 | j7 < 18 | j8 < 18, 1, 0))
```

My expectations:

- The three columns (j6, j7, and j8) indicate ages, and if at lease one of them is less than 18 year-old, the new column (age_event) should be "1", otherwise 0.
- And if the two of the three columns are both 18-year or older and the other is NA, the age_event variable should be 0 .
- Likewise if the one of the three columns is 18-year or older and the others are NAs, the age_event variable should be 0.
- Also it is NA if all of the three columns are NAs.

However, the result and problems are shown as follows:

```
> z
   j6 j7 j8 age_event
1   6 27  8         1
2  19 20 22         0
3  NA NA NA        NA
4  NA  7 20         1
5  NA 19 NA        NA  <-- should be 0, but NA
6  NA NA  8         1
7  NA NA 30        NA  <-- should be 0, but NA
8   8 20 NA         1
9  20 30 NA        NA  <-- should be 0, but NA
10 20  9 NA         1
11 NA NA  3         1
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to turn 5th, 7th, and 9th observations above to 0s using `mutate` and `ifelse`. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

---

Update (2/27/2020): I found a solution with `pmin` when using `mutate` and `ifelse`:

```
z <- z %>% 
        mutate(., age_event = ifelse(is.na(j6) & is.na(j7) & is.na(j8), NA,
                              ifelse(pmin(j6, j7, j8, na.rm = T) < 18, 1, 0)))

> z
   j6 j7 j8 age_event
1   6 27  8         1
2  19 20 22         0
3  NA NA NA        NA
4  NA  7 20         1
5  NA 19 NA         0
6  NA NA  8         1
7  NA NA 30         0
8   8 20 NA         1
9  20 30 NA         0
10 20  9 NA         1
11 NA NA  3         1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rowMeans()` in place of `if_else()` which will handle cases that are all `NA`.

```
z %>% 
  mutate(age_event = +(rowMeans(. < 18, na.rm = TRUE) > 0))

   j6 j7 j8 age_event
1   6 27  8         1
2  19 20 22         0
3  NA NA NA        NA
4  NA  7 20         1
5  NA 19 NA         0
6  NA NA  8         1
7  NA NA 30         0
8   8 20 NA         1
9  20 30 NA         0
10 20  9 NA         1
11 NA NA  3         1
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The data that I made is hypothetical, and I am thinking of using different dataset (much larger). It will probably have such a situation that 14, 30, NA in j6, j7, and j8. The mean of the ages is 22 and it will be coded as 0, although there is 14 in j6.

Comment: @toumai - `rowMeans()` isn't calculating the means of the actual values, but the logical condition that the values are `< 18` (`0` for `FALSE`, `1` for `TRUE`).  Any row that has a mean greater than zero has at least one value less than 18.  Check it against your data, you'll see the results are as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rowSums` to calculate number of `NA` values in a row and number of values that are less than 18. We can then use `case_when` to assign numbers based on different conditions.

```
library(dplyr)

z %>%
  mutate(calc = rowSums(!is.na(.), na.rm = TRUE),
         ls18 = rowSums(. < 18, na.rm = TRUE), 
         age_event = case_when(calc == 0 & ls18 == 0 ~ NA_integer_,
                               ls18 > 0 ~ 1L, 
                               TRUE ~ 0L)) %>%
   select(-calc, -ls18)

#   j6 j7 j8 age_event
#1   6 27  8         1
#2  19 20 22         0
#3  NA NA NA        NA
#4  NA  7 20         1
#5  NA 19 NA         0
#6  NA NA  8         1
#7  NA NA 30         0
#8   8 20 NA         1
#9  20 30 NA         0
#10 20  9 NA         1
#11 NA NA  3         1
```